# How to find the index of the last character of a substring in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to find the index of the last character of a substring in python
Eg : s = "hello"
index of the last character 'e' in s.find("he")

Comment: Hello, You can simply add `len("he") - 1` to the result of `find`. Of course first, You have to ensure that the substring was found.

Answer (score 0):

```py
if substr in s:
    idx = s.find(substr) + len(substr) - 1
    print(s[idx])
```

> In your case substr = 'he'

s.find() returns index of first symbol of substring. You need to add len(substr) - 1 to get index of last symbol of substring

Answer (score 0):

You can do this simply by -

```py
string = "hello"
subStr = "he"
if (string.find(subStr) != -1):
    print(string[string.find(subStr)+len(subStr)-1])

else:
    print("Substring not found")
```

Comment: For this particular example it's fine, but if in case a substring is not found, `find` returns `-1`. If we always add something to it, then we will have incorrect results: `-1 + 1 = 0` - the beginning of a string.

Answer (score 0):

That's should do

```
def get_index(s,substring):
    start = s.find(substring)
    if(start != -1):
        return start + len(substring) - 1
    else:
        print("substring not found")
```